# Cassandra: Create a partitioned table without including the partitioned column name in primary key

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I want to create a partitioned table without including the partitioned column name in primary key.
I am not getting any clue how to create it because most of the examples declaring the clustering column in the primary key section.
I am not sure whether it is doable in Cassandra or not hence seeking some help.

```
CREATE TABLE crossfit_gyms_by_city (  
 country_code text,  
 state_province text,  
 city text,  
 gym_name text,
 year int,
 month int,
 day int);
```

**My requirement is**:
The table should be able to store the data as `Year/Month/Day` partition and by the sorting order of `city`.

Comment: What is your query pattern requirement? Is it to fetch data based on the Year,Month,Day,City? Also I didn't understand you want to partition the table but not mention the columns to partition on when defining the table?

Comment: @Yamini data should be stored as a Year/Month/Day partition sorted by Bity name. My table example is sample table creation, but I do not know how to define partitioned table as per my requirement.

Comment: In Cassandra the table structure is built from the queries requirements... I strongly recommend to take DS220 course before continue

Comment: @Alex working on some urgent deliverable hence instead of checking all the details started working :(

Comment: "I want to create a partitioned table without including the partitioned column name in primary key" - Yeah, Cassandra doesn't work that way.  It needs the partition key in the PRIMARY KEY definition so that it knows *how* to partition the data in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, I am assuming the way you store data is how you plan to fetch it. Based on this assumption I propose the below table structure; 
`CREATE TABLE crossfit_gyms_by_city (
year int,
month int,
day int,
city text,
country_code text,
state_province text,
gym_name text,
PRIMARY KEY ((year, month, day), city));`

So your data will be partition based on `year,month,day` & your clustering column would be `city` so the data is sorted by city

Also I would suggest going through this course which will help you out with your data modelling requirements
https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220?path=developer

Comment: There is some problem with this query.. year/month/day included as a primary key columns so if I perform a upsert operation then it will not be able to recognize as a duplicate records.

Comment: Let me explain you: `country_code,  state_province,  city, gym_name text, year, month, day`
country_code and state_province are the unique identifier for the rows and if I insert a new row having the same country_code and state_province then it will perform the update operation else insert.

year month day values are basically my job run date and if I include these column in primary keys then it won't be able to identify the records uniquely.

Comment: @BlueStar : The thing is I don't understand your requirements completely and have many more questions but if you divulge too many details here you might violate your confidentiality agreement with your employer. Unfortunately there is no shortcut you will need to go through the DS220 course.